# Link files from file system repository to courses in moodle

Tags: php, moodle

I have to create about 2000 course with 5000 documents in Moodle 2.4. I have used Bulk category upload and bulk course upload to create the courses. 
As file management in Moodle 2.0 has changed and files cannot be placed directly to moodle appdata folder. I created file system repository in Moodle Appdata and uploaded all files with their course id (id from DB table after creating courses) as directory name. 
After enabling file system repository i can now see files in file picker. Now i use file picker to link those files to their courses manually. Another option is drag and drop files to their courses. But it is time consuming and it may lead to human error as every course has to be opened and above options has to be done.
I gone through mdl_files table to link files to their courses but the contents are encrypted and i cannot directly link files to their courses using DB as of in course file area in Moodle 1.9. I wrote script using Moodle File API but that could also be done in course only.
Is there any way that linking of those files can be done through script or database to their corresponding courses in bulk.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a solution that doesn't involve writing some code.

However, you could take a look at the code in course/dnduploadlib.php, as that should be possible to adapt this to loop through all the files in a given directory on the server and convert them into resources.

If you created a draft file area (using the files API), you could then use an adjusted version of the 'handle_file_upload' function (and the functions it calls) to do this.